# Can I tell if Chrono consumed the full format string?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

Consider the following

```rust
use chrono;


fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", chrono::NaiveDate::parse_from_str("1978-01-12 01:00:23", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
}
```

The string contains year-month-day-hour-minute-second, but chrono only parsed year-month-day. As expected, because I used `NaiveDate`, not `NaiveDateTime`.

But is there a way to tell (programmatically) that chrono "consumed" the entire format string?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a raw [`StrftimeItems`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime/struct.StrftimeItems.html) and check if any of the items are a time component. There's a lot of variants to go through in [`Numeric`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/enum.Numeric.html) and [`Fixed`](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/enum.Fixed.html), but all of them seem unambiguously time or non-time.

You can check if the string has any of the time specifiers that are listed [here](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime/index.html). So `%H`, `%k`, `%I`, `%l`, etc. You would need to recreate chrono's parsing, but it's not too complex since there's only one special character, `%`.

You can parse a `NaiveDateTime` and check if the result has a nonzero time component. This doesn't really work, since the parsed time could have had `00:00:00`, but maybe that's fine for you.

You can reformat the resulting `NaiveDate` and see if it matches the parsed time. There will be other differences that would need to be ignored, mostly in casing and padding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse`:

```rust
use chrono;


fn main() {
    let d: chrono::NaiveDate = "1978-01-12 01:00:23".parse().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", d)
}
```

Result:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseError(TooLong)', src/main.rs:5:62
```

If you want to use parsing using formats, what stops you from checking that format doesn't contain `%H`, `%M` or `%S`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the implementation of `parse_from_str()` for:

[NaiveDateTime](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/src/chrono/naive/datetime/mod.rs.html#268):

```
pub fn parse_from_str(s: &str, fmt: &str) -> ParseResult<NaiveDateTime> {
    let mut parsed = Parsed::new();
    parse(&mut parsed, s, StrftimeItems::new(fmt))?;
    parsed.to_naive_datetime_with_offset(0) // no offset adjustment
}
```

[NaiveDate](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/src/chrono/naive/date.rs.html#524):

```
pub fn parse_from_str(s: &str, fmt: &str) -> ParseResult<NaiveDate> {
    let mut parsed = Parsed::new();
    parse(&mut parsed, s, StrftimeItems::new(fmt))?;
    parsed.to_naive_date()
}
```

Both implementations seem identical, except for the last row. So the `Parsed` instance used for the `NaiveDate` instance is essentially the same as the one you'd have for the `NaiveDateTime` variant. In other words, the whole format was "consumed" the same way, but in the case of `NaiveDate` you've basically just used the date part of the date-time value you've parsed.

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but I hope that info helps.

If you want to just check if you "lost" a "non-zero" time component (`00:00:00`) by using `NaiveDate`, then I guess you might just parse into a `NaiveDateTime` and check if its `NaiveTime` value is "zero".